# Accepting input in popup before submitting the actual form

Tags: html, spring, forms, popup

I am developing an application using Springs 2.0.

I have a requirement that when user clicks on a submit button on a form, a poup should be displayed showing a "select" box for selecting a predefined reasons and a "Textarea" to accept comment. (These dropdown options are picked from context so can not use static HTML page.)

These 2 values should also be stored in the database along with the other data fields in the parent form.

My problem is: if I use "window.open" then the parent form data does not get carried to child window as it is not "submitted". Also can not submit the form as it will not display popup window.

I tried searching for solution on sites, but could not find solution suitable for me.
Any help would be really appreicated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it using window.showModalDialog and normal java script. Here are the details.

Firstly I defined 2 hidden fields on parent page. When popup window is opened and submitted, the values entered in the dropdown and text area are assigned to those.

```
var handle = window.showModalDialog(htmlURL,this,urlProp);
```

when submitted,

```
document.getElementById("hiddenRejectionComment").value = handle.rejectionComment;
document.getElementById("hiddenRejectionReason").value = handle.rejectionReason;
```

Simple, wasn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Use a div as a popup instead of a new window.  Or use JQuery.  Example, [messi popup](http://marcosesperon.es/apps/messi/) under usage

**Edit**

If you just want something very basic,

```
<div id="modal" style="border:3px solid black; background-color:#9999ff; padding:25px; font-size:150%; text-align:center; display:none;">
    This is a modal popup!<br><br>
    <input type="button" value="OK" onClick="Popup.hide('modal')">
</div>

<a href="#" onclick="Popup.showModal('modal');return false;">Show Modal Popup</a>
<br>
<a href="#" onclick="Popup.showModal('modal',null,null,{'screenColor':'#99ff99','screenOpacity':.6});return false;">Show Modal Popup With A Custom Screen</a>
```

http://www.javascripttoolbox.com

Comment: I am completely new to JQuery. So would prefer to use JavaScript. Can I user window.showModalDialog? I understand that showModalDialog  is not supported in many of the browsers but our users will only be using IE, my purpose would be served, wouldn't it?

Comment: JQuery is JavaScript.  It simplifies JS IMO.  Try it and you will never regret it.  I do not see a need for a new window.  You can take care of all that with simple JQuery and HTML.

Comment: Do you have any sample example showing how to use DIV in this context?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery modal](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/). Here is a similar example which accepts input in a modal http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/modal-form.html.